# Rust join filter and map on the same line of code

Tags: rust

I want to change the value of a specific attribute of a vector of objects.
my code and logic are as follows:

```
let mut person_found: Vec<Person> = persons.clone().into_iter().filter(|x| x.id == "3")
                       .map(|x| x.name = "Carlos".to_string()).collect();

println!("original: {:?}", &persons);
println!("modified person: {:?}", &person_found);
```

But it gives me the following error and I can't understand it well.

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<Person>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `()`
  --> src\main.rs:17:45
   |
17 |     .map(|x| x.name = "Carlos".to_string()).collect();
   |                                             ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<Person>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=()>`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<()>` is not implemented for `Vec<Person>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of an assignment is [`()` (the unit value)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/tuple.html). So if you do `y = (x = 123);` then `x` is assigned `123` and `y` is assigned `()`.

The Rust Reference has a short sentence stating:

> An assignment expression always produces [the unit value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/tuple.html).
>
> – [Assignment expressions - Operator expressions - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#assignment-expressions)

You need to change so it explicitly returns `x` on the next line, for that to work. If you want to mutate `x` then you also need to change `|x|` to `|mut x|`.

```rust
let person_found: Vec<Person> = persons
    .clone()
    .into_iter()
    .filter(|x| x.id == "3")
    .map(|mut x| {
        x.name = "Carlos".to_string();
        x
    })
    .collect();
```

Alternatively, instead of cloning the whole `persons` `Vec` upfront, I'd instead use [`cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) after [`filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) or [`clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) in [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map), i.e. only when needed.

```rust
let person_found: Vec<Person> = persons
    .iter()
    .filter(|x| x.id == "3")
    .cloned()
    .map(|mut x| {
        x.name = "Carlos".to_string();
        x
    })
    .collect();
```

Comment: This is better explained :)

Comment: @Netwave `filter_map` is also great, I'd just move the `.cloned()` into the closure instead :)

Comment: Uhm, yeah, but I wouldnt be able to use `..p` since I take ownership of that right? but I would just clone the needed ones. Gonna update :D

Comment: @vallentin Thank you for making a clear explanation for all of us.

Comment: @Netwave You'd still have to do `..p.clone()`, but at least you wouldn't be cloning already filtered `Person`s :)

Comment: @DanielR.Anccasi Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

You are returning nothing in your map expr line. You can handle with `filter_map` though:

```rust
let mut person_found: Vec<Person> = persons
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|p| 
                (p.id == 3).then_some(Person {
                                     name: String::from("Carlos"),
                                     ..p.clone()}))
    .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f12d4f90db8e8fcc0efb430dd01efff4)

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Where did the Option<Some()> go ?  filter_map() suppose to return an iterator of Option(s).

Comment: @Charlie木匠, what do you mean? The closure parameter in filter map needs to return an option, None values are filtered out. You can return whatever extra computation wrapped in Some

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Where did the Option<Some()> go ?  filter_map() suppose to return an iterator of Option(T). - .
Is the Option<> unwrapped somewhere ? .
It seems I can use the T directly from the result iterator of filter_map().

PlayGround: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=967f933a84b1cddb85428f5b3aeec866

Comment: @Charlie木匠, it is just how flatmap works, you can  think of its signature as a `Iterator<Item=Option<T>> => Iterator<Item=T>` where `None` values from original iterator are filtered out, and some values are unwrapped. That is why it is `flat`, if you want to keep the `Option<T>` use plain `map` instead.

Comment: Great thanks! when seeing flat, I completely understood. So it did kind of flatten() at the end.

Comment: ```let mut person_found: Vec<Person> = persons.iter().filter_map(|p| (p.id == "3").then_some(Person {name: String::from("Carlos"),..p.clone()})).collect();
``` 

is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Indeed @Devil. But I don't recall the and then available in 2021 probably. Feel free to edit the question and add that option as well :)